# How to change date type to dropdown by plugin without change in existing component files

Tags: plugins, joomla, field, components

> I want to change date to drop-down.Let me explain with example for
>   better understand. I have a component that is com_abc.In this
>   component i am using date field in XML. Now i want to change this date
>   field to drop-down list of all dates without touching component any
>   files.i thought i will create a system plug-in for that but i am
>   confused how i call event or search date field in all pages of site
>   and convert it.Is this possible.If possible then please suggest.

Comment: I think there is no way to use plugin for this until the component has any trigger to plugin's event. I suggest you to use jQuery to replace date filed with drop-down

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onAfterRender() event in your plugin. You can get page body like this:

```
$output = JResponse::getBody();
```

Find the code with original date field with preg_match(), replace it with your code and then set new page body like this:

```
JResponse::setBody($output);
```